# How to reinstall OpenCV with different configurations?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.x, cmake, openmp

I have compiled [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) with a couple of flags with [CMake](https://cmake.org) and then installed it with make. More precisely, I did:

```
$ cd ~
$ git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
$ cd opencv
$ git checkout 3.0.0

$ cd ~/opencv
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
$ make -j4
$ sudo make install

$ sudo ldconfig
```

Now I would like to compile [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) with a different configuration. I would add the `WITH_OPENMP = ON` flag, so it would look like this instead:

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENMP=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

What would I need to do to successfully reinstall [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) with [OpenMP](http://openmp.org)? Do I have to do the same exact steps (excluding the git part), meaning that `sudo make install` would override the previous [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) installation? Or do I need to uninstall and remove files, etc?

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I don't know about OpenMP, but I did this with Python support (just added the new flag) and it worked...

Comment: You installed a first version of Python support, then recompiled it with new flags, then reinstalled it and it worked? So if I understand you correctly, you are saying that reinstalling overrides the previous installation?

Comment: If you want to override the old installation just run the commands again (cmake and so on).

If you want to have different versions in the system at the same time try setting a different directory for CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly for each test.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: I want option a) override the old installation. So I guess my assumptions in my question were right. Is there a way to change a parameter without needing to run make again? The `make` command runs for about 1.5h, so it's a loss of time every time I want to test with a different flag.

Comment: I installed without Python support, then recompiled with the Python flag, just like you were assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to reinstall [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) is to rerun the `make` command with the new build configurations, then `make -j4` and finally `sudo make install`. This overrides the old installation.